# How can I call an "EditorFor" for a specific class from _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model, html-helper

Basically, instead of writing plain old Html to build a form, I would like to invoke a helper method and have that return what I need.

```
<div class="contacto-container">
    <h1>Envíenos sus consultas:</h1>

    @Html.Editor("BuzonDeSugerenciaModel", "BuzonDeSugerenciaModel")

    <div class="separator"></div>    
</div>
```

This isn't really doing what I think it would do.

It outputs:

```
<input id="BuzonDeSugerenciaModel" 
       class="text-box single-line" 
       type="text" value="" name="BuzonDeSugerenciaModel">
```

And not the collection of inputs I declared in the Model class, `BuzonDeSugerenciaModel`.

If this were a strongly type View, it would be fine if I went:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

However, since this is run in the _Layout.cshtml file, I need something else. I can't quite figure out a way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a partial view that is strongly typed to your `BuzonDeSugerenciaModel` class. This partial view will live in your `Views > Shared` directory.

Something like this (`_BuzonDeSugerenciaModel.cshtml`):

```
@model BuzonDeSugerenciaModel

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Then, in your _Layout.cshtml, you can call:

```
@Html.Partial("_BuzonDeSugerenciaModel", Model.buzonDeSugerenciaModel)
```

You will need to pass an instance of `BuzonDeSugerenciaModel` as the second argument  to `Partial()`. If you do not have one passed form the `Controller`, something like this will work:

```
@Html.Partial("_BuzonDeSugerenciaModel", new BuzonDeSugerenciaModel())
```